# Angular 2 RC6 - "sidebar" is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I just updated to RC6 and have trouble with the following error:

> zone.min.js:1 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   'sidebar' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'sidebar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'sidebar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("

`sidebar` isn't a component. Just a html-tag i am using in one of my templates. They look like this:

```
...
<sidebar class="main-nav">
    ...
</sidebar>
...
```

I tried updating my NgModule AppModule with `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` like this:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [...],
    imports: [BrowserModule, routing, HttpModule, FormsModule, TranslateModule.forRoot()],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

Does anyone haven an idea or a hint?

Comment: It seems related to [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11219)

Comment: You're right. I have to implement a workaround...

Comment: just have a look at mine answer, I'd rather solve it in different way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to [Pankaj Parkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2435473/pankaj-parkar) for his comment.

`sidebar` seems not to to be accepted yet. I had to implement a workaround.

**sidebar.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * dummy directive to allow html-tag "sidebar"
 */
@Directive({ selector: 'sidebar'})
export class SidebarDirective {}
```

**Include it in `app.module.ts`**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [..., SidebarDirective],
...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Ok, this fixed it. But... really? There must be a better way... Or what, now we're not supposed to use any non-standard HTML5 tags? :(

Comment: I've followed the new boston tutorials and I'm guessing it's not up to date. For what solved it was adding my custom component to the app.module.ts, thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than go for `workaround` I'd say that whenever you wanted to create component, have some suffix before component selector. Like suppose my application name is `MoneyManagement` so then I'll be adding `mm-` before each of my application component. This habit will reduce the chances to conflict with any reserve HTML `tag`/`element` or `sidebar` component added by plugin.

Unlike the workaround would not work in future when you add bootstrap/any plugin component here which has `sidebar` component already defined.

Just following such kind of convention would avoid this issue in future.

```
<mm-sidebar class="main-nav">
    ...
</mm-sidebar>
```

Comment: But "sidebar" is not a custom element. It is a commonly used html5-tag that angular2-team "forgot" to add/accept as allowed element.

Comment: @Philipp sorry my answer was little unclear, please look at updated answer. My whole point is don't use generic selector while creating component, just have some prefix before it to avoid future conflicts in component